iPhone creates Bluetooth interference for Mac (headphones, keyboard, trackpad etc)
My iPhone sitting next to me at my desk with Bluetooth enabled. My headphones (Bose) are paired to both iPhone and my apple silicon Mac running macOS Sequoia. Periodically Bluetooth goes haywire globally. A key I'm typing will get repeated as the keyboard connection glitches. Headphone clicks in and out over a second.
When I disable Bluetooth on my iPhone, this interference doesn't happen.
I've had this happen across multiple laptops and iPhones over the years, and it's quite frustrating.
I've tried disabling my Wi-Fi routers 2.4GHz band, and it doesn't seem to help.
I would prefer to not always turn off Bluetooth on my iPhone while working.

From your description of where this happens, I’m assuming this glitches in the same physical location. You mention “laptops” so I am also assuming this is happening on a laptop, not a desktop.  Can you take your setup to another location temporarily and eliminate any possibility the glitch occurs because of some Bluetooth interference from some other, perhaps unknown, device?

The only thing I can think of is that unlike say USB, Bluetooth is not a bus.  It is a point to point connection.  Sure, you can have multiple devices connected, but only one connection is active at a time.  I am guessing, in a time slice manner.  The more devices you have connected, the more glitchy it can become.
